# Starting Tor at boot fails: Unknown option 'Kog'

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I'm attempting to build a raspberry pi tor router with a Raspberry Pi 2 model B using an 8GB SD card. Tor wont start for some reason, the error code below is what keeps popping up, but sadly I've found nothing scouring the web.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status tor.service
● tor.service - LSB: Starts The Onion Router daemon processes
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tor)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-05-27 15:12:10 BST; 9min ago
  Process: 1424 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tor start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi tor[1424]: Checking if tor configuration is valid ... failed!
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi tor[1424]: May 27 15:12:10.314 [notice] Tor v0.2.5.12 (git-3731dd5c3071dcba) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.1t and Zlib 1.2.8.
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi tor[1424]: May 27 15:12:10.314 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi tor[1424]: May 27 15:12:10.314 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi tor[1424]: May 27 15:12:10.314 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi tor[1424]: May 27 15:12:10.328 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'Kog'.  Failing.
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi tor[1424]: May 27 15:12:10.328 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: tor.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts The Onion Router daemon processes.
May 27 15:12:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit tor.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: Check for a syntax error.

Comment: What's a "Kog"?

Comment: @PandaLion98 Based on the error message, I'm guessing an "unknown option" somewhere in the tor configuration...

Comment: @goldilocks `Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'Kog'.  Failing.` What the heck is a Kog? If it's not a valid option, it may just be a typo by OP.

Comment: @PandaLion98 Yes, in fact this may be something the OP cut n' pasted without reading and so is not aware of.  I edited this and changed the title from the classic, always appropriate, *"Can you help me solve this error?"* ;)